# How to ensure all subtasks are requeued until successfully completed in a task executor

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a task executor that runs multiple subtasks concurrently using a thread pool. The goal is to run the subtasks with a maximum of 5 threads. However, I encountered a bug in my code.

```
    def run(self):
            while self.tasks:
                if len(self.tasks)!=0:
                    task = self.tasks.popleft()
                    future = self.task_executor.submit(task.run)
                    self.submitted_tasks[future] = task
                    future.add_done_callback(self._handle_task_result)
            self.task_executor.shutdown(wait=True)
     

    def _handle_task_result(self, future):
       
        if future.exception() is not None:
            self.tasks.append(self.submitted_tasks[future])
```

The problem is that if the last subtask in the task queue pop out , the executor shuts down and the loop breaks. As a result, the failed subtask cannot be requeued for reexecution.

I would like to know how I can fix this bug. Specifically, I want to ensure that the executor does not shut down until all subtasks have completed, and all failed subtask requeued again and again until all task successfully completed. How can I modify my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the `run` method to use `concurrent.futures.as_completed` in the following way (note that attribute `self.tasks` no longer needs to be a `deque` instance):

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, tasks: list):
        # tasks only needs to be a list
        self.tasks = tasks
        self.task_executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(5)

    def run(self):
        # While there are tasks to run or retry:
        while self.tasks:
            print(f'Running {len(self.tasks)} tasks:')
            # Can and should be a local variable:
            submitted_tasks = {
                # Submit all tasks
                self.task_executor.submit(task.run): task
                for task in self.tasks
            }

            # Wait for all tasks to complete
            # and create new task list of tasks to retry:
            self.tasks = [
                submitted_tasks[future]
                for future in as_completed(submitted_tasks)
                if future.exception() is not None
            ]

        self.task_executor.shutdown(wait=False)


class Task:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def run(self):
        # Force an error if n is 3 or 5:
        n = self.n
        if n in (3, 5):
            # Modify so that it will not fail when retried:
            self.n = -n
            raise ValueError(f'Bad n: {n}')
        print(f'{n} ** 2 = {n ** 2}')


tasks = [Task(n) for n in range(7)]
SomeClass(tasks).run()
```

Prints:

```None
Running 7 tasks:
0 ** 2 = 0
1 ** 2 = 1
2 ** 2 = 4
4 ** 2 = 16
6 ** 2 = 36
Running 2 tasks:
-3 ** 2 = 9
-5 ** 2 = 25
```

**Method 2**

If you wish to submit a failed task immediately upon detecting that it completed with an exception instead of waiting for all previously submitted tasks to complete, then modify method `run` as follows:

```py
...
class SomeClass:
    ...
    def run(self):
        print(f'Running {len(self.tasks)} tasks:')
        # Can and should be a local variable:
        submitted_tasks = {
            # Submit all tasks
            self.task_executor.submit(task.run): task
            for task in self.tasks
        }

        while submitted_tasks:
            # Wait for tasks to complete and submit retries:
            submitted_tasks = {
                self.task_executor.submit(submitted_tasks[future].run):
                    submitted_tasks[future]
                for future in as_completed(submitted_tasks)
                if future.exception() is not None
            }

        self.task_executor.shutdown(wait=False)

    ...
...
```

Comment: Did this answer your question or did I misunderstand it?